# Are web3 domains bought at Freename.io in conflict with web3 domains bought at GoDaddy?

Tags: dns

It seems like there's 2 companies competing for the same space here in the web3 domain minting process. I am curious to know if a web3 domain that's been 'minted' from freename.io totally reserves that domain from the Polygon network, or if someone minting their domains from GoDaddy could also mint the identical domain (messing things up for everyone). My HOPE is that web3 domains minted by either company are truly unique and not able to be conflicted by the same web3 domain minted by the other company. Does anyone know?

I have only purchased a web3 domain at freename.io, and since web2 browsers don't yet support web3 domains, it's difficult to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every web3 Domain is unique and connected with smart contracts on Blockchain.

Godaddy is a Web2 Domain registrar. Recently they have partnered with ENS and working on ENS web3 domain provider. ENS only supports .eth Domain names which is completely unavailable on Frrename. Neither Freename supports .eth extension Domain name for minting nor Godaddy supports any of the Freename TLD/Domains to mint on any blockchain.

There is no collisions here.